# Function to create a matrix filled with a count of the times a number shows up in a table but only if another column is unique

Tags: r, matrix, count, data-manipulation

This may be a complicated question. I have a data frame X with columns particle, source, and Sink. My goal is to create a matrix where the rows are the source numbers and the columns are the sink numbers. The matrix should be filled with a count of the times a the Sink number appeared per source number if the particle number is unique to that source/Sink combination.

The data frame looks like this:
[Dataframe X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfAF6.jpg)

The expected output should look like this:
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhjDl.jpg)

You can see particle 1 from source 1 is found in sink 1 twice but is only counted once. However, particle 1 from source 1 is found in sink 4 so it is counted under column 4 as well. If the particle is found in the same source/sink combination more than once it is only counted once. However, if the particle is found in multiple sinks from the same source it is still counted.

I honesty have attempted to use the unique function, but have had extreme difficulty getting it to correctly calculate. I would like to create a function to do this.

I have added another example where I added a row. The highlighted values in the dataframe X would lead to the highlighted value in the new matrix. The idea here is that because the particle number is different it adds one, but particle number 1 appears twice in sink 1 so it does not get counted twice.
[New_Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLWr7.jpg)

[New Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME196.jpg)
As well as not counting a particle twice if it is in the same sink, I need to count the number of times a particle from the same source enters the sink if the particle number is unique.

edit: New Data

```
structure(list(Location = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Particle = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), Time = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Long = c(272.302, 272.302, 
    272.302, 272.302, 278.695, 278.695, 278.695, 278.695, 277.323, 
    279.544, 279.12, 279.085, 279.766, 277.323, 272.302, 279.766, 
    279.544, 278.754, 279.12, 279.845, 279.766, 272.302, 272.302, 
    279.766), Lat = c(17.14, 17.14, 17.14, 17.14, 24.681, 24.681, 
    24.681, 24.681, 27.612, 27.865, 28.997, 24.87, 27.419, 27.612, 
    17.141, 27.419, 27.865, 24.679, 28.997, 27.37, 27.419, 17.141, 
    17.141, 27.419), Depth = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_), Distance.x = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 100L, 200L, 300L, 50L, 200L, 300L, 500L, 400L, 300L, 
    450L, 350L, 400L, 300L, 200L, 300L, 600L), Source = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Sink = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 8L, 
    5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

code I am using:

```
Dummy_Data_Con_Table <-
  Dummy_Data %>%
  select(Source, Sink, Location, Particle) %>%
  group_by(Sink,Source) %>%
  summarise(unique = n_distinct(Particle, Location)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  right_join(expand.grid(Source= 1:8,Sink =1:8)) %>%
  replace_na(list(unique = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Source, names_from = Sink, names_prefix = "Sink", values_from = unique)
```

The only difference is that I also added the stipulation that the combination of Particle and Location had to be unique. I used this code a couple of weeks ago and it worked. I cannot figure out what I changed to break it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would really help if you could provide a reprex: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I want to make sure I have this right: you have a 1 in the (1,1) entry of your matrix, even though the combination (source = 1, sink = 1) occurred twice. Is this because (source = 1, sink = 4) also occurred, or are ALL these numbers just flattened down to 1? I ask because your first paragraph makes it seem like it's the first reason, but your paragraph right after the expected output makes it seem like it's the second reason.

Comment: There is a 1 at (1,1) of the matrix even though it happens twice because the value in the particle column of data frame X is the same between both instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic R approach:

```
mat <- matrix(rep(0, 64), ncol = 8)
mat[as.matrix(df)] <- 1
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1    1    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    1    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1
[7,]    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
```

Or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df$unique = 1

expand.grid(source = 1:8, sink = 1:8) %>%
  left_join(distinct(df)) %>%
  replace_na(list(unique = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = source, names_from = sink, names_prefix = "Sink", values_from = unique)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 9
# Groups:   source [8]
  source Sink1 Sink2 Sink3 Sink4 Sink5 Sink6 Sink7 Sink8
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
2      2     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
3      3     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0
4      4     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
5      5     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0
6      6     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
7      7     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
8      8     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

**Edit**:

Here is a revised approach that considers the number of different particles that share the same `sink` and `source`.

```
df %>%
  group_by(sink, source) %>%
  summarise(unique = n_distinct(particle)) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  right_join(expand.grid(source = 1:8, sink = 1:8)) %>%
  replace_na(list(unique = 0)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = source, names_from = sink, names_prefix = "Sink", values_from = unique)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 8 x 9
  source Sink1 Sink2 Sink3 Sink4 Sink5 Sink6 Sink7 Sink8
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1      1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
2      2     1     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
3      3     0     0     1     1     0     0     2     0
4      4     0     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
5      5     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     0
6      6     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
7      7     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
8      8     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

**Edit**:

With revised data, and base R, you could also consider the following:

```
df$source = factor(df$source, levels = 1:8)
df$sink = factor(df$sink, levels = 1:8)

df2 <- aggregate(particle ~ source + sink, df, function(x) length(unique(x)))

xtabs(particle ~ source + sink, data = df2)
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(
  particle = c(1:7, 1:7, 1:9),
  source = c(1:7,1:7,1:8,3),
  sink = c(1,1,4,6,7,8,5,4,6,7,5,4,8,3,1,3,3,4,3,3,1,5,7)
)
```

Comment: This would work for my original example. However, I need the function to add 1 to the matrix if the particle number is unique. I have added an updated example to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Hey Ben. It has been a while but I just came back and attempted the code and you generously supplied. It is giving me a new error which I cannot figure out why. It says: Error: `by` required because the data sources have no common variables. However, I have not changed anything. It is an issue with the right join. Do you have any idea what this might be? I have tried to ungroup so that maybe the Sink and Source variables will be visible again but to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: I added the data and the code I am using. I edited a couple of things like selecting the columns I needed and adding the stimulation that location and particle must be unique. These worked a couple of weeks ago when I was testing this. There must be something small I did to the data frame to break the code. I just cannot figure it out.

Comment: @asnead94 Thanks - I just tried it out with your `Dummy_Data` and code, and it worked fine for me, no errors. Have you tried restarting R? Clean session? Upgrading packages (e.g., `tidyverse`/other)?

Comment: I just restarted the R session and used the same exact markdown cell and it worked. I have not idea what happened. I should have remembered sometimes just turn it off and back on.